# git update mirror without affecting new branches

Tags: git, gerrit

1. git clone --mirror https://original/repo.git
2. git remote add gerrit ssh://mirror/path
3. git push gerrit --all
4. cloned the mirrored repo

   $git clone ssh://mirror/path

I have created new-dev branch in mirrored repo and working on new-dev branch and pushing the changes to "ssh://mirror/path" on same new-dev branch

mean while I have observed that some of the branches in https://original/repo.git are updated. How to mirror those changes again to same "ssh://mirror/path" without affecting new-dev branch

Comment: A mirror (or "fetch mirror" as made by `git clone --mirror`) slavishly throws out everything *it* has and completely re-mirrors whatever you cloned when you use `git fetch` on that mirror. Never use this kind of fetch mirror to store important data; use it only as a *cache* to make it faster to retrieve data that 's stored in the repository it mirros.

Comment: I want to maintain one repository in server, from server group of users will clone and do developments on it(new-dev branch) and push changes to server using gerrit. i want to update repo in server from its origin if origin has some new changes. How to do this?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a server that (a) is the single sole source of truth for every developer, and yet (b) is never the sole source of truth for any developer because the actual source of truth is "its origin". This can *only* work if the server in (a) is the actual source of truth for the server in (b), i.e., you reverse the dependency direction for your server repository and its (currently) upstream so that what was its upstream is another downstream.

Comment: The other alternative is not to treat the upstream as the source of truth at all: if the upstream changes, some designated *human* person (or group) must take the upstream's changes, incorporates them in some way, and update the server repository. So it is not a mirror at all, but rather an independent repository with humans maintaining it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I was having a similar issue and I think this is how to do it: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-repo-sync

This can be added the github actions, or you can explore the source code and see how they do it and do it yourself manually.